# Output answers in to textfile?

Tags: ruby, shoes

I'm using ruby and shoes to create a test for some students. I want to know how to have them click a button and their answers in the text boxes are sent to the desktop in a text file format. Thanks.

Comment: Please add more to the description of the problem. What have you tried so far?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a request to write code, with no evidence of any effort or research having been done, and no description of any specific problem that the asker is having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
File.open('path/to/desktop/answers.txt', 'w') do |file| 
  file.write('answers')
end
```

Comment: This is a pretty generic answer.  While it answers the vague gist of the question asked, I'd be amazed if it actually solves the guy's problem.

Comment: I hear you on all that, I just think the question is so vaguely worded that you're overly optimistic about all that stuff you inferred.  :)  It's a lot to read between the lines, no?

Comment: @SperanskyDanil You answered my question! Thanks so much!

Comment: @SperanskyDanil in the file.write('answers') i tried to call my variable there but it just writes the name of the variable?

Comment: @SperanskyDanil file.write(answer1)

Comment: @SperanskyDanil Now i tried instead of |file| i put |f1| and instead of file.write i put f1.puts "#{answer1}"     and it outputs to the text file - (Shoes::EditLine)

Comment: @SperanskyDanil this is what im trying to do http://pastie.org/6376402

Comment: @SperanskyDanil I'm rather new to this language mate, i could use some help. I believe edit_line creates a line where you can type in.